# Capture audio with naudio and play with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, audio, naudio, naudio-framework

I have a client with written c# and a server with written java. I capture audio and send with socket to the server and server send with web socket to the browser and want to play with browser. But when i try browser says Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
Could you help me?

```
private static void Recordwav()
    {
        waveInEvent = new WaveInEvent();
        int devicenum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < WaveIn.DeviceCount; i++)
        {
            if (WaveIn.GetCapabilities(i).ProductName.Contains("icrophone"))
                devicenum = i;
        }

        waveInEvent.DeviceNumber = devicenum;
        waveInEvent.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, WaveIn.GetCapabilities(devicenum).Channels);
        waveInEvent.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(VoiceDataAvailable);

        waveInEvent.StartRecording();
    }

private static void VoiceDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        JObject jObject = new JObject();
        jObject["voice"] = Convert.ToBase64String(e.Buffer);

        byte[] messageByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jObject.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "") + "\n");
        socket.Send(messageByte);
    }

$scope.socket.onmessage = function (response) 
{ 
    var data = JSON.parse(response.data);
    if(data.id == $scope.id) {
        if(data.voice) {
            var voice = data.voice;
            var sound = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64," + voice);
            sound.play();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What is that Audio class you used in last event and then passed base64 to it . . ?

Answer (score 0):

you're just sending raw samples, not a properly formatted WAV file. You'd need to use `WaveFileWriter` to write to a `MemoryStream` (wrapped in an `IgnoreDisposeStream`) dispose the `WaveFileWriter` and then access the `MemoryStream` underlying byte array. Also you're not taking into account `BytesRecorded`.

Even if you get this working, I suspect you'll get very choppy audio, as each WAV file will be a few hundred ms, and they won't necessarily play perfectly one after the other.